# Stripe webhook refund, how to get the original chargeId from Charge object

Tags: c#, stripe-payments

I process the Stripe subscriptions initial payment and store the charge-id against the payment in my DB.
If the user triggers a refund via the stripe site i trap this via the web-hooks.
I want to retrieve the charge Id from the charge object that is passed to the web-hook call so i can flag the payment as refunded.
I can't see this in the charge object, how would i get something to identify the original payment charge id?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? I don't really understand the exact underlying question, which object you are look at, etc. But when a refund is created, it describes the Refund object https://stripe.com/docs/api#refund_object and then it has a `charge` property with the original charge id

Comment: Hi koopajah, sorry for lack of clarity.
I create a subscription which creates a customer and payment.
I get the charge id returned from stripe for the payment.
i store the charge id in my db
When a refund notifies my refund webhook i want to know the payment charge id that this refund refers to. So i can mark it as refunded in my db.

Comment: The event for the refund has the charge id in the `charge` property: https://stripe.com/docs/api/refunds/object#refund_object-charge